# How to retrieve the different range of values from database using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently trying to retrieve light values and sort them into a pie chart using an ajax pie chart tool. I really need help for the SQL statement for retrieving and counting the different set of values.

**Here is the 3 sets of values i want to retrieve:**

1) retrieve and count lightValues that are < 24

2) retrieve and count lightValues that are between 24 and 30

3) retrieve and count lightValues that are > 30

The pie chart is the result i want to achieve. Currently I am using a raw data to display what i want to achieve.

**Image for pie chart:**

[image]

**Image for database:**

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want to get.

Comment: I want to get something like the pie chart which i've already posted an image above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way

```
select
    count(case when lightvalue < 24 then 1 end),
    count(case when lightvalue between 24 and 30 then 1 end),
    count(case when lightvalue > 30 then 1 end)
from tbl
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'less_than_24' AS group_name, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM table_name
WHERE lightValue < 24
UNION ALL
SELECT 'from_24_to_30', COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM table_name
WHERE lightValue BETWEEN 24 AND 30
UNION ALL
SELECT 'more_than_30', COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM table_name
WHERE lightValue > 30;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/430337)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════╦═════════╗
║  group_name   ║ counter ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════╣
║ less_than_24  ║       4 ║
║ from_24_to_30 ║       2 ║
║ more_than_30  ║       2 ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════╝
```